# Show the following second derivative expression.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem : If $I(t)=\frac{N}{(N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}+1}$, then show that

$\dfrac{d^2I}{dt^2}=\left[ \dfrac{N^3(N-1)\gamma^2 e^{-\gamma Nt}}{[1+(N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}]^3}\right][(N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}-1]$

**My attempt:**
$I(t)=\frac{N}{(N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}+1}$
$\implies \log I=\log N-\log[(N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}+1]$
$\implies \dfrac{I'}{I}=\dfrac{1}{N}-\dfrac{1}{(N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}+1}\left[ (N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}(-\gamma N)\right]$, where $I'=\dfrac{dI}{dt}$

I stuck here. Can any one proceed further to show the required result or any other alternative way?

**Added:**
[image]

Comment: Are $N$ and $\gamma$ constants? According to your computations with some mistakes, this is unclear... If so, why taking logs and not derivating directly twice as the inverse of a function?

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Yes $N, \gamma$ are constants

Comment: The derivative of $1/u$, with $u$ a non-vanishing function, is $-u'/u^2$. Can you try a direct computation from this, with $u(t)=(N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}+1$ here? And for the second derivative, you must know how to differentiate $u/v$, with $u$, $v$ two functions with $v$ non-vanishing.

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Ok. I'm trying

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Done

Answer (score 2):

I would consider approaching it along these lines re-writing the equation for $I$ and differentiating:
$$
I(t)=\frac{N}{(N-1)e^{-\gamma Nt}+1}=\frac{N}{f(t)}\\
\Rightarrow I(t)f(t)=N
$$
Differentiate
$$
If'+I'f=0 \tag{1}
$$

$$
 \Rightarrow I'=-If'/f=-Nf'/f^2 \tag{2}
$$

Now differentiate (1) again to get the 2nd derivative involved
$$
If''+f'I'+I'f'+fI''=0 \\ \Rightarrow If''+2I'f'+fI'' = 0
$$
Sub. for I' from (2) and for $I=N/f$

$$
I''=-\frac{N}{f^3}\left( f \,f''-2 \left( f'\right)^2 \right)
$$
and take it from there.